# Nextjs internalization middleware problem

Tags: next.js, next.js13, i18next

I've a problem to make my nextjs app structure multilanguage, the problem is that in middleware i have the languages ["ar", "en"] but when i try to go to any route while the `ar` is active it convert the `url` to en automatically and when i print the languages in the `Negotiator` it returns `[ 'en-US', 'en' ]` and i can't find the problem. this is the middleware code

```js
import { match } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from "negotiator";

let locales = ["en", "ar"];
let defaultLocale = "ar";

function getLocale(request) {
    const acceptedLanguages =
        request.headers.get("accept-language") ?? undefined;
    let headers = { 'accept-language': acceptedLanguages }
    console.log(acceptedLanguages, "acceptedLanguages");
    let languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages()
    console.log(languages, "languages");

    return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale) // -> 'en-US'
}

export function middleware(request) {
    // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
    const pathnameHasLocale = locales.some(
        (locale) =>
            pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`
    );

    console.log(pathnameHasLocale, "pathnameHasLocale");

    if (pathnameHasLocale) return;

    // Redirect if there is no locale
    const locale = getLocale(request) || defaultLocale;
    request.nextUrl.pathname = `/${locale}${pathname}`;
    // e.g. incoming request is /products
    // The new URL is now /en-US/products
    return Response.redirect(request.nextUrl);
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        // Skip all internal paths (_next)
        "/((?!_next).*)",
        // Optional: only run on root (/) URL
        // '/'
    ],
};
```